# Storing first characters of elements in a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

How can I store the first character of an element in a string? E.g. if I run

```
for (j=0; j < 5; j++) {
    printf("%s\n, string[j]);
}
```

I get

```
hello
how
are
you
```

Thanks to the answer provided by @Holy semicolon, I know that I can run `printf("%c\n, string[j][0]);` to print the first letters:

```
h
h
a
y
```

However, how can I store the first letters in a new array?
So far, I have:

```
char secondStr[10];

for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
    secondStr[j] = string[j][0];
}
```

This results in an error ***assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast***

I know this question is slightly different to the one I asked before (regarding printing the first elements) - I was unsure whether or not to ask an entirely new question on SO. I apologise in advance if I was supposed to ask a new question.

Comment: string1 is a **single** string, not an array of multiple strings. take a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? If that means "write" then it's an error to write to a string literal, but is unclear without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would like to store it in a variable.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I hope my edit has made it clearer

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Assuming `string1` has been correctly defined, it very well can be valid C. Of course it does not mean what OP thinks.

Comment: The first element of a C string (actually also of a Python string) **is** a character. I'm not sure what you mean by "first character of the first character" though.

Comment: I guess you did `printf("%s\n",string[0][1]);` instead of `printf("%c\n",string[0][1]);`. Please show the code that produces the problem, so we don't need to guess.

Comment: FYI: `string[0][1]` is the **second** character in the first string

Comment: Jasmine078, I hope you won't delete your question again, without a warning, since people may have put effort in answering it.... I had asked you for an MCVE before, you ignored me. Now, you post a new question, really similar to the old one, and @WeatherVane has to ask you for an MCVE again... That's not the spirit of SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you have an array of pointers to char `*string1[] = {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};` and you want to print the first string of it `hello`, you must use `%s` for string like this `printf("%s", string1[0])` but if you want to print the first char of the first string you need to use `%c` like this `printf("%c",string1[0][0])`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *string1[] = {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
    printf("%s", string1[0][0]);  // I think you did this error, It'll give you a Segmentation fault                                                                                                         


    return 0;
}
```

so as you see in the above code you need to replace `%s` with `%c`.

## Edit

> What if I wanted to store the first letters in a new list?

you will need then to allocate memory to the new string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *string1[] = {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
    char **keep = calloc(sizeof(char*), 5);    //memory allocating

    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        keep[index] = calloc(sizeof(char), 2);     //memory allocating
        keep[index][0] = string1[index][0];   
        keep[index][1] = '\0';      //not necessary since calloc fill the allocated cases with 0
    }

    //for testing
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%c\n", keep[i][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear response. What if I wanted to store the first letters in a new list? Should I post this as a new question on SO?

Comment: @Jasmine078 do you want to store them in a string or in a char ?

Comment: I would like to store them in a separate string

Comment: `string1` is not an array of strings, but an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: @Jasmine078  Edited.

Comment: @HeIs Thank you very much. Although your code prints the expected result, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Jasmine078 Fixed, My bad :)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If string is std::string, then:

```
    string s[6] = { "hello","how", "are", "you", "?" };

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
    {
        if(s[j].size())
        printf("%c\n", s[j].c_str()[0]);
    }
```

Should word.

Comment: Wrong language. This is not C.

Answer (score 0):

Many options are there. I will just mention some.

1. Use begin()

   ```
   for( int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )
   {
         string:: iterator it = String[i].begin();
         cout << *it;
   }
   ```
2. Use front()

   ```
   for( int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )
   {
         cout << String[i].front();
   }
   ```
3. Use at()

   ```
   for( int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )
   {
         cout << String[i].at();
   }
   ```

You can just go through the member functions of string and use it to your purpose

Comment: The question is about C, not about C++